# Thermal Imaging camera activation upon detection

Tags: wheeled-robot

So I am planning on building a robot that turns on when it detects some kind of heat source, I am currently looking at thermal imaging cameras, but am not sure as to how to go about writing code to send a ping or some sort of message when the camera detects a heat source.

Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with `if objectDetected() then sendPing()`? What part of the process are you having trouble with?

Comment: Oh right, I guess it was mainly the knowledge that something like that existed! My question would then be, how do I set objectDetected to equal a heat source through a thermal imaging camera? I assuming that I would need some kind of software to actually process the image taken by the camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chuck 's comment is correct; You can have some sort of polling software which detects some image (continuously tries to detect an object from image stream).

Else, if this does not work, then, it is better to add some other sensor like proximity sensor or so to detect objects like human and then turn on thermal camera if a threshold is crossed. But, as @Chuck mentions, unless the objectives are known, it is difficult to help you out.

If an image-array is obtained, then image-processing can be done through many libraries. Some of the libraries which I remember are OpenCV, MATLAB, PIL (Python Imaging Library), BoofCV, JavaCV, SimpleCV etc (depending on your programming language).